# curl response cannot be handled after saved in a variable PHP

Tags: php, html, curl

```
$ch = curl_init("http://acrs.bboxpr.com/getAddress.php?lat=35.545112&lng=-90.657635");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$address = curl_exec($ch);       
curl_close($ch);

//prints the address
echo $address;

//$token = strtok($address, ",");
//$phaddress=array();
//while ($token != null)
//{
//array_push($phaddress,$token);
//$token = strtok(",");
//}
//print_r($phaddress); //blank
```

In the line `echo $address;` will print in the content in the page, but if I uncomment the code below(the one that starts with: `$token=strtok`),$address will look empty. I added more code that uses the results with $address (but I did not include that in here) and sometimes appears the source-code of the site that is invoked in the curl initialization.  So I think maybe curl is taking a little bit longer, but I tried to put a sleep before srtok, but didn't work.

Comment: Can you show what is the value of `$address`

Comment: Is $address on this line "$token = strtok($address, ",");" already empty? You can echo $address after this line... is this empty?

Comment: I don't know if its important but the page in the curl init, uses "d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(variablejs));
 document.body.appendChild(d);" this  code to update the body of the page.

Comment: Tobi, if I uncomment the while loop even the first echo will print nothing, if I add another below prints nothing also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are tying to get MAP information from google i think you are using the wrong approch my using `javascript` because that might be more difficult to parse

Why don't you try using `PHP` directly

```
$ch = curl_init("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.545112,-90.657635&sensor=false");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$geoOutput = json_decode($return,true);
echo "<pre>" ;

foreach($geoOutput as $key => $data)
{
    if(is_array($data))
    {
        foreach($data as $cKey => $cData)
        {
            var_dump($cData['formatted_address']);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
string(43) "6724-6916 Bay Ln, Harrisburg, AR 72432, USA"
string(16) "Bolivar, AR, USA"
string(25) "Harrisburg, AR 72432, USA"
string(17) "Poinsett, AR, USA"
string(13) "Arkansas, USA"
```

Comment: how can I get the first result without the String(43)? and put that in a variable?

Comment: use `print` instead of `var_dump`

Comment: Thank you!, I change the code as you said, I think that the problem I had with the other code is because the URL used in curl, contained java-script to generate the body.

Answer (score 2):

In your `while` loop, you have to replace `$token = strtok(",");` with `$token = strtok($address, ",");`

Comment: I did it and a 500 error appears, I tried the while loop with a value for $address, like: $address="12,31231,123123,123,132"; and the strtok makes his work. But since it works with "echo" I tried to cast the variable into a String but didn't work.

Comment: the url has been updated, you can see the sourcecode of that file: http://acrs.bboxpr.com/getAddress.php?lat=35.545112&lng=-90.657635 I want to have the body in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop to this: `while ($token !== false)`